# Some svg animations play in GitHub README others do not

Tags: python, animation, github, svg, github-flavored-markdown

I have been checking out some terminal to svg recorders like [termtosvg](https://github.com/nbedos/termtosvg) written in Python and [svg-term-cli](https://github.com/marionebl/svg-term-cli) in Typescript.

I installed *termtosvg* and recorded a small terminal session to keep in my README as a demo. However github doesn't render it. Strangely it renders all the svg [animations that termtosvg](https://nbedos.github.io/termtosvg/pages/templates.html) has.

*svg-term-cli* is using *Rawgit* to render, but I don't want to use it as [it will be taken down](https://rawgit.com/).

I made a small repository for testing purposes [here](https://github.com/armsp/howto-render-svg). I downloaded one svg from *termtosvg*, one from *svg-term-cli* and one of my own and put it in `docs` folder in the repo. And linked to them from my `README.md`.

#### **Issue**

The svg animation from *svg-term-cli* renders in README however the **other two don't**.

**NOTE:**

- Inside `docs` folder I can clearly see Github rendering the animated svgs.
- I'd like to use termtosvg and not svg-term-cli.

Why is this happening? How do I make README render my animated svg.

Answer (score 3):

I had a chat with the creators of *termtosvg* and found out that *termtosvg* uses `animation` tags which GitHub considers as scripts thereby removing them. That's why we see just a black screen and no animation when we try to link svgs output by *termtosvg*.

*svg-term-cli* and the shark animation on the other hand uses CSS to achieve the same thing which GitHub doesn't seem to have an issue with. That's why they get rendered.

**Possible workarounds:**

1. Using github.io to host the images and link that to README as that seems to work.
2. Using Rawgit. But keeping in mind that it will be taken down soon.